# Unable to covert data to Latin 1 on Linux using PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I am trying to loop through a set of javascript files, detect their encoding and then save them both in latin1 and in utf8 format. So far I have really gotten stuck at trying to get PHP to convert a UTF-8 file to Latin1. I have tried several different methods of encoding the data after searching around but nothing seems to work.

Here is what I am doing:

```
//Read file 
$fileIn = fopen($dirName . $fileNameIn, 'r');
$dataIn = fread($fileIn, filesize($dirName . $fileNameIn));
fclose($fileIn);

$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($dataIn);
echo "Encoding in: " . $encoding . "\r\n";

$dataOut = utf8_decode($dataIn);

echo "Encoding after: " . mb_detect_encoding($dataOut) . "\r\n";
```

Both of these printouts print UTF-8 as the detected encoding. Any ideas?

Could this have anything to do with the fact that the system default on my ubuntu box is UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the iconv function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php):

```
string iconv ( string $in_charset , string $out_charset , string $str )
```

Therefore, try writing

```
 $dataOut = iconv($encoding, "ISO-8859-1", $dataIn);
```

and see if that fixes the problem. Also, try using strict mode in mb_detect_encoding:

```
mb_detect_encoding($dataOut, mb_detect_order(), true);
```

Comment: This conversion seems to work in the sense that the detection now reports that the encoding has changed. However, when written to disk, PHP still creates a UTF-8 file.

Comment: I might have missed to convert some data because this is working now (although detection is not that reliable)

Answer (score 1):

[`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) might be a misnomer, as it's technically not possible to detect encodings. If you don't know the encoding, you can only guess (see [Summaries of supported encodings](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.encodings.php)).

So technically spoken, a string can have multiple encodings but `mb_detect_encoding` will only return one value. And as written, it's not technically possible to detect an encoding.

As you check for a *specific* encoding, you can make use of the additional parameters:

```
echo "Encoding after: " . mb_detect_encoding($dataOut, 'ISO-8859-1', TRUE) . "\r\n";
```

Maybe this helps, checks for `ISO-8859-1` only and does it strict.